# MVC4 RenderAction causes stack overflow in _Layout.cshtml

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to implement a menu within my `_Layout.cshtml` view:

```
@Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
@{ Html.RenderAction("Index", "Home"); }

@if (@ViewBag.Menus != null)
{
    foreach (vw_UsuarioPerfilMenuFuncionalidade memo in @ViewBag.Menus)
    {
        if (memo.IdMenuLast == null)
        {
            <li><span>@memo.NomeMenu</span></li>
            foreach (vw_UsuarioPerfilMenuFuncionalidade memo2 in @ViewBag.Menus)
            {
                if (memo.IdMenu == memo2.IdMenuLast)
                {
                    <li><span>@memo2.NomeMenu</span></li>
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I load the page, a `System.StackOverflowException` is thrown:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in System.Web.dll

Why is that?

Comment: I would think it is linked to iterating the same collection in nested foreach loops (@ViewBag.Menus).  I would wonder if you should be iterating something different in your second foreach.

Comment: But If I run the  @Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home"), work fine whitout any problem, but the Menu will be only on one page inside the BodyRender

Answer (score 5):

I think that's because you have:

```
@{Html.RenderAction("Index", "Home");}
```

which return `View`, then it take `_Layout.cshtml` and infinite loop...

Comment: I think that`s right so any adivice to implements Menu <Section> on _Layout?

Comment: @LucasRodriguesSena Put menu in the `PartialView` and render it with `Html.RenderAction` from controller, add caching and everything will be fine ;)

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar problem and got answer from below link.

https://forums.asp.net/t/2130287.aspx?RenderAction+Infinite+Loop

First step, remove below code

```
@{Html.RenderAction("Index", "Home");}
```

and it should be:

```
@Html.Action("Index", "Home")
```

The second step:

At your partial view, set the layout with null:

```
@{ Layout = null; }
```